# Does a logarithmic branch point imply logarithmic behavior?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms

The complex logarithm $L(z)$ is given by $$L(z)=\ln(r)+i\theta$$ where $z=re^{i\theta}$ and $\ln(x)$ is the real natural logarithm. It is well known that $L(z)$ then sends each $z$ to infinitely many values, each of which are different by an integer multiple of $2\pi i$. If we imagine going along the unit circle in the $z$-plane starting from $1$ and working anti-clockwise, the image of it under $L(z)$ will be a segment of the vertical line $i\theta$ with $\theta$ a real number. However we clearly see how $1$ has mapped to $2$ different values, and how we could continue on mapping it to infinitely many values by winding around $0$ indefinitely. We then call $0$ a *Logarithmic branch point* of the mapping.

My question is, do there exist mappings that have logarithmic branch points that themselves have nothing to do with logarithms *i.e.* the logarithm does not appear explicitly somewhere in it's definition or it does not behave like a logarithm. Does a logarithmic branch point indicate logarithmic behavior?

Comment: Should be:Different by an integer multiple of $2\pi i$.

Comment: Do you feel the arctangent function behaves like a logarithm? If not, it would qualify.

Comment: $arctan(z)=\frac{1}{2i}ln(\frac{1+iz}{1-iz})$, so I don't think that qualifies. See http://www.math.ethz.ch/education/bachelor/lectures/fs2012/other/ka_itet/TrigHypFunktionen.pdf

Comment: Opps... The "image of it under $L(z)$ will be a segment of the vertical line" $i\theta$, not $1+i\theta$!

Comment: The only function I can think off is the branch points of the [incomplete elliptic integrals](http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegrals/EllipticF/introductions/IncompleteEllipticIntegrals/ShowAll.html). Since its inverse are elliptic functions which are doubly periodic in $\mathbb{C}$, every time one loops around a branch point, one will pick up same period like what happens for "Log / Exp".

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have an answer;

$f(z)=z^p$ with $p$ an irrational number. If $p$ is rational, then the order of the branch point $f(z)$ at $z=0$ is just the denominator in lowest terms. So if we take the limit as $p$ goes to an irrational number, we should get an infinite order branch point.

Comment: This will be an infinite sheeted Riemann surface, but I'm not sure what you mean by non-logarithmic. Note that $z^p = \exp(p\log z)$.